# NodeJS global variable within a request function

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I have currently following code:

```
var request = require('request');

var variable1;

request('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/EUR.json', function (error, response, body){
    var btceurpricejson = (body);
    var obj = JSON.parse(btceurpricejson);
    variable1 = (obj.bpi.EUR.rate_float);
});

function getBTCItemPrice() {
        console.log(variable1);
};

getBTCItemPrice();
```

But it always only outputs `undefined`. When I use `console.log(variable1);` in the request function, it works. But when I use it like above, in another function, it doesn't work. Even though I use a global variable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Simply saying, when you create a variable and leave it without assigning a value to it, JavaScript will automatically assign a value called undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This should work call your function in your request callback.

```
var request = require('request');

var variable1;

request('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/EUR.json', function (error, response, body){
    var btceurpricejson = (body);
    var obj = JSON.parse(btceurpricejson);
    variable1 = (obj.bpi.EUR.rate_float);
    getBTCItemPrice();
});

function getBTCItemPrice() {
        console.log(variable1);
};
```

Comment: At that point you might as well ditch the global variable and call `getBTCItemPrice` *with* the data.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bad practice to use global. But as said above calling `getBTCItemPrice()` inside the callback will serve your purpose.

Comment: Yea thanks, now that that worked, I was able to use `getBTCItemPrice(variable1);` and `function getBTCItemPrice(variable1) {
        console.log(variable1);
};` So that means, I don't longer need a global variable.